Unable to customize/edit taskbar after recent update to Bookworm for my RPI 4B
I recently updated Bookworm-64 on my RPI 4B, and cannot customize taskbar. Previously I would right click on it and get  an option to configure size, autohide and delete it.
How to delete the taskbar and use cairo dock?
